# RSpec test to expect only certain properties of an ActiveRecord model to change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am successfully testing whether certain properties of an ActiveRecord model are updated. I also want to test that ONLY those properties have changed. I was hoping I could hook into the model's `.changes` or `.previous_changes` methods to verify the properties I expect to change are the only ones being changed.

**UPDATE**

Looking for something equivalent to the following (which doesn't work):

```
it "only changes specific properties" do
  model.do_change
  expect(model.changed - ["name", "age", "address"]).to eq([])
end
```

Comment: If you come along and down vote I would love to know why. If this is a test that shouldn't be written for some fundamental reason I, and others, might benefit from learning why. If it's because of the way the question is written then share your displeasure so I can improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
expect { model.method_that_changes_attributes }
  .to change(model, :attribute_one).from(nil).to(1)
  .and change(model, :attribute_two)
```

If the changes are not attributes, but relations you might need to reload the model:

```
# Assuming that model has_one :foo
expect { model.method_that_changes_relation }
  .to change { model.reload.foo.id }.from(1).to(5)
```

EDIT:

After some clarification from the OP comment:

You can do this then

```
# Assuming, that :foo and :bar can be changed, and rest can not

(described_class.attribute_names - %w[foo bar]).each |attribute|
  specify "does not change #{attribute}" do
    expect { model.method_that_changes_attributes }
      .not_to change(model, attribute.to_sym)
    end
  end
end
```

This is essentially what you need.

This solution has one issue though: it will call `method_that_changes_attributes` for each attribute, and this can be inefficient. If that's the case - you may want to make your own matcher that accepts an array of methods. Start [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/lib/rspec/matchers/built_in/change.rb#L84)

Comment: This is essentially what I'm currently doing in my test. What I would like to do is to make sure ONLY those properties have changed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help:

```
model.do_change
expect(model.saved_changes.keys).to contain_exactly 'name', 'age', 'address'
```

this is supposed to work with `.previous_changes` too.

if the changes are not saved then `.changed` should work.

At the end of the day this is really dependent on how things happen on `do_change`

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing we can do,

```rb
  let!(:model) { create(:user, name: 'old_name', age: 29, address: 'old_address')
  let(:name) { 'New name' }
  let(:age) { 30 }
  let(:address { 'new address' }

  it { expect { model.do_change; model.reload }.to_not change {
    model.attributes.slice!("name", "age", "address", "updated_at") } }

  it { expect { model.do_change; model.reload }\
    .to change { model.name }.from('old_name').to(name)\
    .and change { model.age }.by(1)\
    .and change { model.address }.from('old_address').to(address) } }
```

This is how I work around the inefficiency mentioned in @Greg 's answer but either can be faster depending on the number of attributes to check,

but make sure to assign different initial values on `model.create` and watch out for `updated_at`, which is sometimes read as unchanged (ignoring partial milliseconds).

P.S. if anyone knows how to combine these two in a single test, Please comment.